# How to handle browser authentication in Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to automate a web application deployed in an websphere application server environment. Websphere has application security enabled, so to access the application an username and password is required in the browser popup box. I am having a hard time automating the username password entry in this box from selenium webdriver. Most of the answers found on google suggest using "user:pass@URL" format, but this does not work for me. I am using firefox as a browser and using java as the language. How to solve this issue ?

Comment: See Robot utility: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Comment: Don't use Robot. Its a flaky solution

Comment: Have managed to set up a dirty solution using robot. Had help from one of the devs, wrote a custom class with robot keypress events for all the letters as well as special characters inside a huge switch case block, and spawning a thread with appropriate timeout and exception handling from the main program. The solution is quick and dirty, but it works. Not posting this as an answer, cause there might be some "proper" solution.

Answer (score 0):

How do you approach in situations where you enter username and password in normal window? Don't you externalize username and plain passwords in config files? If security is concern, save in encrypted format in config files and decrypt at run time. Getting around the JS popups is not easy and straightforward, using Robot solution is flaky too.

Send username and password through url like `http://username:password@your-app.com`. This should work.

```
 String url = "http://username:password@your-app.com";
 driver.get(url);
```

Comment: `Most of the answers found on google suggest using "user:pass@URL" format, but this does not work for me`.  I think for privacy issues, they don't want to expose their user/pass

Comment: @sircapsalot my bad, I missed that part in the question. I updated answer.